# Calculate the  sum of time datatype in sql

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to calculate time datatype in sql for the purpose of calculate employee's monthly working hour which obviously will grater than 24 hours(it should be at least 132hours).But the time data type doesn't supports greater than 23:59:59.9999999 . But i need to calculate monthly working hour.

Comment: Why would you use the `TIME` data type to store an interval? Wouldn't it make more sense to store start and end time using `DATETIME` or `SMALLDATETIME`, or store duration in minutes in an `INT`?

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand You are right but my project manager is decide that. so i have nothing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure `Total working time` is given as `Time` datatype?
Your sample input is '32:23:00' which is not supported by 'time' Data type
Because its range is `00:00:00.0000000 through 23:59:59.9999999`.

If it is `Time` datatype, then you can calculate the salary as juergen states:

```
select cast(cast (100.00 as money) * datediff(second, 0, '23:23:00') / (60.0 * 60.0) as money)
```

*I cast the values into money data type to show that, its possible to multiply it with datediff() functions returned value.*

Comment: Yes I am sure it's in time format.Your answer is very good but it's not work when hour is greater than or equal 24

Comment: @yeasir007: Yes it won't work because the time data type doesn't supports greater than 23:59:59.9999999. If you sure about the data type then you couldn't be able to handle the larger values.So think about any other data type.

Comment: If daily working hours is likely 8 hours than if i sum one employee's total working hours due to one month obviously is grater than 24 hours.So how can i solve this, Please suggest if you have any good idea.

Comment: I think i have a problem to find sum of total working hours.Please tell me how can i sum total working hour where daily working time is in time format.

Comment: @yeasir007: In sql you could not use time data type to store your working hours. So use another data type like decimal.

Comment: Its most obvious that you must use a front end program with this database. You can handle this stuffs easily in your front end program.Just query them into your program and parse them into appropriate data type and make the calculation easily.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10213/discussion-between-yeasir007-and-abdur-rahman)

Answer (score 1):

You can substact dates with the `DATEDIFF` function.

The result can be mutiplied with your salary.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, '12:00:00', '12:30:00') / 60.0 * 100.0
```

Comment: sorry total working hour is in time format not date-time. it's a sum of   daily working hours due to a month.Simply i need to multiply salary per hour(like 100.00) with total working hour(like 32:23:00 which already sum of working hours but in time format)

Comment: @ juergen d Hi  juergen  thanks for response.problem is solved now ,i was some problem to calculate sum of time but now that's are solved.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with this code and the problem is solved now.

```
sum(datediff(second, 0, timeYouWantToSum)) / 3600.0
```

will give you the number of worked hours as a decimal.Now I am able modify this total working hour by round/floor/ceiling and also able to multiply with salary per hour.Thank you